# What are the hidden stats for all the characters?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

Each character has hidden stat bonuses for Speed, Weight, Acceleration, Handling, Drift, Off-Road, and Mini-Turbo. How much does each character boost each stat?

Answer (score -2):

## Lightweight characters

```
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|     Name     | Speed | Weight | Acceleration | Handling | Drift | Off-Road | Mini-Turbo |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|  Baby Daisy  |   5   |    6   |       0      |     0    |   0   |     0    |      3     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|  Baby Luigi  |   5   |    8   |       0      |     0    |   0   |     0    |      0     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|  Baby Mario  |   0   |    8   |       0      |     6    |   0   |     0    |      0     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|  Baby Peach  |   3   |    6   |       3      |     3    |   0   |     0    |      0     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|   Dry Bones  |   0   |    0   |       3      |     0    |   3   |     0    |      6     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
| Koopa Troopa |   0   |    0   |       0      |     3    |   0   |     0    |      6     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|  Mii (Light) |   3   |    3   |       0      |     0    |   3   |     0    |      3     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|     Toad     |   0   |    0   |       6      |     0    |   6   |     0    |      0     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|   Toadette   |   3   |    0   |       0      |     0    |   0   |     6    |      0     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
```

## Mediumweight characters

```
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|     Name     | Speed | Weight | Acceleration | Handling | Drift | Off-Road | Mini-Turbo |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|     Birdo    |   0   |    3   |       0      |     0    |   0   |     3    |      5     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|  Bowser Jr.  |   0   |    0   |       0      |     0    |   0   |     3    |      3     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|     Daisy    |   4   |    0   |       0      |     2    |   0   |     0    |      3     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|  Diddy Kong  |   0   |    0   |       3      |     0    |   3   |     0    |      5     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|     Luigi    |    2  |    6   |       0      |     0    |   0   |     0    |      0     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|     Mario    |   0   |    6   |       2      |     2    |   3   |     0    |      0     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
| Mii (Medium) |   3   |    3   |       0      |     0    |   0   |     3    |      3     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|     Peach    |   2   |    0   |       5      |     0    |   6   |     0    |      0     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|     Yoshi    |   0   |    3   |       0      |     0    |   3   |     5    |      0     |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
```

## Heavyweight characters

```
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|     Name    | Speed | Weight | Acceleration | Handling | Drift | Off-Road | Mini-Turbo |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|    Bowser   |   2   |    5   |       0      |     0    |   3   |     0    |      0     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
| Donkey Kong |   0   |    3   |       2      |     2    |   0   |     0    |      3     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|  Dry Bowser |   0   |    0   |       0      |     0    |   0   |     6    |      6     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|  Funky Kong |   4   |    0   |       0      |     0    |   0   |     3    |      0     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|   King Boo  |   0   |    0   |       0      |     5    |   0   |     3    |      0     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
| Mii (Heavy) |   3   |    0   |       3      |     3    |   3   |     0    |      0     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|   Rosalina  |   3   |    0   |       0      |     3    |   0   |     0    |      3     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|   Waluigi   |   0   |    0   |       6      |     0    |   5   |     3    |      0     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
|    Wario    |   0   |    3   |       0      |     0    |   0   |     3    |      6     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------------+----------+-------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: You obviously got this list from somewhere; you should link where, as we frown rather heavily on plagiarism.